# Nut butter with water. Shelf life

Tags: nuts, nut-butters

I have a blender that is not very powerful, just 400 Watt. I tried to use it with nuts and it cannot do it, I notice it suffers too much. If I add some water it works well and I like the result. My question is how much time will the cream last in the fridge?

What I have tried:
- I tried to make just what I need for today. The blender needs more quantity to move everything.
- I tried to add lemon. It seems to work with savory recipes but not if I want a sweet cream, sauce or spread.

If I make a cream, sauce or spread with nuts and a bit of water, how much time will it live well in the fridge?

None of the sources commented answers the question. It is known that nut butters have long shelf life as natural oils help to preserve them. The question here is if adding water can shorten the regular shelf life of a nut butter.

Comment: I added more information to explain why those answers do not fully address my question

Comment: As soon as you mix ingredients and process them in some way (and this can be as easy as cutting) your food counts as "cooked dishes", which is covered in the duplicate question, unless you have worked from a recipe tested for producing long shelf life (e.g. if you are making pickles). Food safety does not recognize fine gradations in shelf life.